# function returning undefined variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple function to count the number of rows in a database and return the result. However I am getting the result returned as undefined, even though if I console.log the result it is coming up correctly from within the function. Here is the gist of what I am doing although I have stripped out a lot of code to simplify it.

```
$('#roomsList').append(getCount(currentRow.roomtype));


function getCount(roomtype) {
var query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fixturesfittings WHERE roomtype = ?;"
localDatabase.transaction(function (trxn) {
    trxn.executeSql(query, [propertyid,roomtype],function (transaction, results) {
       return results.rows.item(0)["COUNT(*)"];
    },errorHandler);
});
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I suppose getCount() is async done by transaction

Comment: you have only roomtype in query but you are sending propertyid and roomtime for execution, could that be causing your sql to not return anything?

Comment: Thanks Hanky Panky although no, I just stripped that out of the code to simplify things, the other answers were correct in that the function is asynch..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two equally serious problems with what you're doing:

1. Your *outer* function doesn't return anything. The only `return` statement in your code is returning from the *inner* function being passed to `localDatabase.transaction`.

   Something like this:

   ```
   function myFunction
     inner_function = function () {
       return 3; # Return from inner function, *not* myFunction
     }
   }
   ```
2. Even if you *were* attempting to communicate a value out of your inner function to the outer function and then returning from the outer function, it still wouldn't work; the inner function is being invoked asynchronously. That inner `return results...` is being invoked at some point in the future, long after `getCount` has finished executing and returned `undefined`. You need to pass in some form of callback into `getCount`; the callback will be invoked later and passed the count. Think of it this way:

   ```
   function myFunc(callback) {

     function inner_function = function(callback) {
       // Invoke our callback sometime in the future
       setTimeout(1000, callback);
     }

     // Inner function does some processing at some future time;
     // give it a callback to invoke when its processing is done
     inner_function(callback);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks everyone, the asynchronisity of javascript still baffles the hell out of me - especially since I keep trying to make it behave synchronously. Javascript and Jquery is new to me and although I get the concept, it still all seems foreign to me! Thanks for all your help, it all makes sense now.

Comment: It seems like asynchronous development is supposed to make things quicker but actually slows things down...

Comment: It has nothing to do with making *development* quicker. JavaScript is single threaded. Asynchronous callbacks are meant to allow the browser to remain responsive rather than becoming completely frozen during every AJAX request. The alternative to async callbacks is actual threading, which (in terms of complexity) makes async callbacks very attractive.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `localDataBase.transaction` and `exequteSql` are asynchronous functions. They won't have their answer right away, which is why you pass the functions into them. Once they gets an answer, they calls your function, known as a callback. This will happen at a later point in the execution cycle, after `getCount` is long gone.

So `getCount` calls `localDatabase.transaction`, which gets to work but doesn't have anything immediately available, so `getCount` finishes before the data is available, and so `getCount` is returning undefined (the default return value in JavaScript functions).

You will probably need to rework your code to something like this:

```
getCount(function(count) {
    $('#roomsList').append(count);
});

function getCount(callback) {
    var query = '...';
    localDatabase.transaction(function(trxn) {
        trxn.exequteSql(query, ...  function(transaction, results) {
            callback(results);
        });
    }
}
```

This is a very common pattern JavaScript, and has lots of pitfalls and oddities to it. It takes some getting used to.